# JavaFX 2.2 How to resize a chart based on another

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I would like to modify the height of y-axis of ChartB whenever ChartA's y-axis is resized 
(eg: `chartB.yAxis = chartA.yAxis*0.5`).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean the height (number of pixels), or do you really mean the bounds (i.e. the range of values plotted)?

Comment: @James_D number of pixels.

Comment: chartB.prefHeightProperty().bind(chartA.heightProperty().multiply(0.333));
  chartB.minHeightProperty().bind(chartA.heightProperty().multiply(0.333));
  chartB.maxHeightProperty().bind(chartA.heightProperty().multiply(0.333));

The above code works, but I'm not sure if this is the right way.

Comment: I was just going to post that as an answer... of course that gives 1/3 the height, not 1/2, but htat works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chartB.prefHeightProperty().bind(chartA.heightProperty().multiply(0.5)); chartB.minHeightProperty().bind(chartA.heightProperty().multiply(0.5)); chartB.maxHeightProperty().bind(chartA.heightProperty().multiply(0.5));`

Explanation: 
Start with Chart B's height property (prefHeightProperty, minHeightProperty and maxHeightProperty) and bind that to Chart A's height property by a factor of 1/2, which means every time Chart A's height changes, `chartA.heightProperty()` will provide the new height of Chart A this value is multiplied by 1/2 or 0.5 to get the new height value in pixels for Chart B. The bind API on Chart B would consume this new height value and set the pref height, min height and max height on Chart B.

Note: The only way to exactly control the height of Chart B is by binding all the 3 properties i.e., prefHeightProperty, minHeightProperty and maxHeightProperty

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.